# auth0: token data appeared in the url and event authenticated did not raise

Tags: angular, auth0

I am trying to login using Auth0 from Angular2 app. The code is derived from [Auth0 sample](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login). It was working but now the behavior is a bit weird.

Token data appended to the url:

> http://localhost:4200/#access_token=0ZoQ3U6Ma2tAhQnh&id_token=eyJ0e...jqd&token_type=Bearer

event `authenticated` did not raise:

```
@Injectable()
export class Auth0Service {

  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('I21EAjbbpfPh...', 'xxx.au.auth0.com', {});

  constructor() {
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      // Use the token in authResult to getProfile() and save it to localStorage
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function(error, profile) {
        if (error) {
          // Handle error
          return;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
      });
    });
  }
...
```

Any idea pls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2-auth0: the login is not working after adding hash to url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641554/angular2-auth0-the-login-is-not-working-after-adding-hash-to-url)

Answer (score 1):

`LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` are added to resolve routing url probblem when refreshing the page however it causes issue to `Auth0` function.

Removing them in `app.module.ts` to get `Auth0` function back.

```
//{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
```